# Form input is undefined

Tags: angularjs, forms, view, model

Why the name and password are undefined?
I've used ng-model on them...

```
 <form class="login" name="form">
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': isInvalidLogin}">
                <label for="name">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nitzan">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': isInvalidLogin}">
                <label for="password">Password: </label>
                <input type="password" ng-model="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="1234">
                <p class="help-block" ng-if="isInvalidLogin">Name or password are wrong!</p>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success login-btn" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
        </form>
```

In the controller:

```
 $scope.login = function () {
        usersService.get($scope.name, $scope.password).then(function success(result){
           $scope.currentUser = result;
        }, function error() {
            $scope.isInvalidLogin = true;
        });
    };
```

See the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/QD3vtil3w9pd4d1TGl9v?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because of `ng-if` directive which is creating child scope from current scope. Hence $scope.name & $scope.password is undefined inside `$scope.login` function.

I'd suggest you do create one object for `user` which is initially blank like `user={}` or you can do this on html using `ng-init`, then put it inside of `mainController` so that it can directly access by the parent without doing `$parent.` notation.

And place `name` and `password` inside user object.

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-init="user={}">
    <div class="container login-div" ng-if="!currentUser">
      <form class="login" name="form" ng-submit="login()">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': isInvalidLogin}">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nitzan">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': isInvalidLogin}">
          <label for="password">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" name="test" ng-model="user.password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="1234">
          <p class="help-block" ng-if="isInvalidLogin">Name or password are wrong!</p>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success login-btn">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CODE**

```
    $scope.login = function () {
        alert("Name "+ $scope.user.name +"& password is " +$scope.user.password)
        //usersService.get($scope.name, $scope.password).then(function success(result){
        //   $scope.currentUser = result;
        //}, function error() {
        //    $scope.isInvalidLogin = true;
        //});
    };
```

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2LH0CtaSFLhKABW4Kuix?p=preview) here.

**Update**

Otherwise you need to add change your ng-model to refer this scope to parent scope like

**HTML**

For name `ng-model="$parent.name"`

For password `ng-model="$parent.password"`

**CODE**

```
   $scope.login = function () {
        alert("Name "+ $scope.name +"& password is " +$scope.password)
        //usersService.get($scope.name, $scope.password).then(function success(result){
        //   $scope.currentUser = result;
        //}, function error() {
        //    $scope.isInvalidLogin = true;
        //});
    };
```

[Plunkr Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cnhn4fMQv9wgO6HncFCI?p=preview)

Hope this could help you. Thanks.

Comment: ng-if creates a child scope, but name and password are outside it (not nested) so why they are in the ng-if child scope?

Comment: @EmeraldBach yes ng-if creates child scope from current scope https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf#!

Comment: But name and password are not nested inside the ng-if - ngmodel is not inside ng-if

Comment: @EmeraldBach have you gone through the question. Please do look at html inside this Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/QD3vtil3w9pd4d1TGl9v?p=preview ..Form tag is inside `ng-if="!currentUser"`

Comment: @EmeraldBach Thats not good thing..Actually you added the question and  I'm explaining you what you have added.. Thanks,